"Chrome is undefined" error when using chrome extension API in next.js
I am trying to send a message through chrome API from my next.js app to the extension app. I'm using useEffect to call this function in one of my .tsx context files like this:
useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof chrome !== 'undefined') {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage("jhcakhflaiggoonphjfkpejmnldbdhho");
      console.log('ran')
    }
  },  [isJwtValid]);

This code doesn't run, it always returns "chrome is undefined". How can I run this code in my next.js app?

chrome.* APIs are for use in extensions only and I don't think any website can just call them.
